# How to draw closed surfaces with vis.js graph3d.js?

Tags: javascript, 3d, surface, vis.js

I try to draw 3d closed surfaces with graph3d.js in vis.js but I can only draw functionnal surfaces (x,y) -> z. Is there a way to draw closed surfaces?

A quick code:

> ```
>       // create the 3D elliptope - the set of of 3x3 correlation matrices
>         var steps = 51;
>         var maxval = 1;
>         var valstep = 2 / steps;
>         for (var x = -1; x <= maxval; x+= valstep) {
>             for (var y = -1; y <= maxval; y += valstep) {
>                 for (var z = -1; z <= maxval; z += valstep) {
>                     det = 1 + 2*x*y*z - x*x - y*y - z*z;
>                     if (det >= 0 && det <= 0.05) {
>                         data.addRow([x,y,z]);
>                     }
>                 }
>             }
>         }
> ```

Below the problem with the surface which is not closed, i.e. only one of the two z-values is chosen:
[image: not closed surface]